# How to dynamically bind xml or json data to bootstrap grid? how to make bootstrap grid editable?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm new to bootstrap. My background is Asp.net but I haven't worked on the MVC architecture, but worked on only n-tier architecture. I was searching which is best and commonly used techniques to develop responsive asp.net application and I came across bootstrap as being best for responsive development with asp.net. I was just going through bootstrap grid. I could not find anyway to dynamically bind columns from returned data set (XML/j son), so that number of columns are created dynamically.

Another question is how do I make bootstrap grid editable without using any third party framework?

Answer (score 0):

Like you I was an ASP.net guru and went on to use ASP.net MVC since it's inception, and the short answer is: you don't (or at least you don't have to).

In the world of MVC, bootstrap, JavaScript and jquery there are very useful JavaScript libraries that you can take advantage of. I recommend you use the [Datatables Library](https://datatables.net). It easily binds to JSON data and is responsive as well.

Also check out the [Admin LTE site](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html). It will show you how a site can be built with just Bootstrap and JavaScript libraries.

Comment: thank u so much, admin LTE looks very useful for a beginner like myself. I am sorry to have confused you with my question. I wanted something like datagrid control (where I can just bind a dataset to just bind that many columns in dataset) in bootstrap.Or a editable datagrid in bootstrap. I couldn't find similar control features in jqueryUI as well. I think i have to used plugin like Datatables Library.